# File Handling and Arraylists error

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

I'm trying to add a list of phrases from the text file `"ListOfElectronics.txt"`, to the ArrayList `"electronics"`.

I'm getting an error here:  `electronics.add(fileIn.nextLine());`

It's saying `"no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String)"`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

/***
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("\f");

        ArrayList<Electronics> electronics = new ArrayList<Electronics>();

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner fileIn;

        try
        {
            fileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader("ListOfElectronics.txt"));

            while (fileIn.hasNextLine())
            {
                electronics.add(fileIn.nextLine());
            }

            fileIn.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't give a String to a list that expects an object of the class `Electronics`. You may need to get the string, turn it's contents into an Electronics object, then add it to your list.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
ArrayList<Electronics> electronics = new ArrayList<Electronics>();
```

with

```
ArrayList<String> electronics = new ArrayList<>();
```

Otherwise, it's expecting you to add objects of a class of a type called `Electronics`.

If you do have a class called `Electronics`, that you're looking to add to the Arraylist, and if it has a constructor that calls for a `String`, you can replace the add string with:

```
electronics.add(new Electronics(fileIn.nextLine()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Electronics class looks like this

```
public class Electronics {  
   private string name;

   public Electronics(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

then you could just replace:

```
while (fileIn.hasNextLine())
        {
            electronics.add(fileIn.nextLine());
        }
```

with

```
while (fileIn.hasNextLine())
        {
           Electronics electronics = new Electronics(fileIn.nextLine();
           electronics.add(electronics);
        }
```